# Interpretation of the Elements of the Leontief Inverse (Total Requirements Matrix)

Tags: macroeconomics, international-trade, leontief, input-output

I found what I believe to be slightly different interetations of the individual elements of the Leontief Inverse (total requirements matrix):

[Miller and Blair (2009)](http://digamo.free.fr/io2009.pdf) just after Equation (2.12) mention that for the Leontief Inverse $\mathbf{L}$

$
(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A})^{-1}=\mathbf{L}=[l_{ij}]
$

elements $(i,j)$ can be represented as

$
\partial x_i / \partial f_j = l_{ij}
$

where

$x_i \dots$ output of sector $i$ 
$f_j \dots$ final demand for output of sector $j$

On the other hand, [Crama et al. (1984)](https://orbi.uliege.be/bitstream/2268/217602/1/Structural%20decomposition%20multipliers%20input-output.pdf) on the first page mention that *(variables changed to fit the convention used by Miller and Blair)*

> Each element $(i, j)$ of $\mathbf{L}$ gives the variation in output of the sector $i$, due to an increase of one unit of output, in the sector $j$.

While they do not provide an equation, this would be equivalent to (?)

$
\partial x_i / \partial x_j = l_{ij}
$

Which is correct? Am I misinterpreting the description by Crama et al.?

I am aware of [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/23781/) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/139801/), but I believe neither provides sufficient information to answer my own.

Comment: Hi @Wasserwaage. Demand-driven IO analysis has a passive supply side and fixed prices. The equilibrium process in demand-driven IOA is based upon supply quantities responding to exogenous demand shocks. The Leontief inverse thus solves for the necessary supply/input changes given a demand shock to keep the process in equilibrium. Section 2: https://strathprints.strath.ac.uk/61254/1/Swales_Turner_2017_Environmental_economics_handbook_of_input_output_analysis.pdf

Comment: I think both sources I found use the demand-driven convention. From what I understand from Section 2 of your document, it supports the definition used by Miller and Blair. Unfortunately, I don't see how it answers my question.

Comment: The next breath is of course: elements measure the portion/share of inputs to sector J, which comes from sector I, and thus the corresponding change in these portions given a demand shock. If I am missing something, I know longer know how to help. Your title is better worded than the question, must say. Someone will provide a superior answer to me, but I think the Q needs more focus.